# How do I apply an armature to a model with a mirror modifer with pre-assigned vertecies?

Tags: armature, weight-painting, mirror-modifier

I am making a model for a game that uses the mirror modifier as I attach the armature to it. All the bones and vertex groups have been labeled correctly. However, the issue is there are no vertices on the right side of the body (the mirrored part, there is nothing to select). So now, the model parts follow the left side of the body.

Now, I could always apply the mirror modifier, but then I would lose the ease of symmetry. I don't want to apply the modifier because I plan to reuse this model. I've tried googling everywhere how to fix this and found nothing. I am using Blender 3.5.

[image: Base model in default pose][image: Left arm raised][image: Right arm raised]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because you need to create empty vgroups on your model to match the other side.

For example, if your bones/vgrroups are called Arm.L, Leg.L, etc. you need to add additional vgroups labeled Arm.R ad Leg.R.  IMPORTANT: do NOT assign any verts to these groups or it wont work propperly

The mirror modifier DOES mirror vgroups and DOES differentiate between left and right, but there needs to already be a right side vesrion vgroup for the modifier to put the flipped data into. (At least, I think that's why)

Comment: Had no idea I needed to add those extra vertex groups. Thank you so much for the quick response! Everything works exactly as I hoped!